# Data through FirebaseRecyclerOptions takes about 2-3 seconds to render in activity output

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am not sure if this is normal but haven't seen the same behavior on other app on play store. I am developing this app where i am using FirebaseRecyclerOptions to fetch data from Firebase. it takes about 2-3 seconds for data to render in activity.

Here is my code:

```java
    public class Offline extends Application {
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        }
    
    }
```

And in activity:

```java
    RecyclerView chatScreenRecyclerView;
    ChatSingleAdapter chatSingleAdapter;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        startFirebaseRecyclerViewOptions();
    }

    private void startFirebaseRecyclerViewOptions() {
        DatabaseReference tempDatabaseReference = databaseReference.child("Chats").child(senderNode);
        tempDatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);
        Query query = tempDatabaseReference.orderByChild("timeStamp");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ModelChatSingleScreen> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelChatSingleScreen>()
                .setQuery(
                        query,
                        ModelChatSingleScreen.class
                )
                .build();

        chatSingleAdapter = new ChatSingleAdapter(ChatSingle.this, getApplicationContext(), options);
        chatScreenRecyclerView.setAdapter(chatSingleAdapter);
    }
```

My Firebase Database structure is *Chats* >> *Sender Node* >> *Chat Node* >> *Chat Node Properties*. There are about 25 *Chat Node Properties* under each *Chat Node*. Structure shown below:

```
    {
      "Chats" : {
        "1-2" : {
          "0tQ3BrPCWzl2021073014020032" : {
            "backgroundTaskIndicator" : "0",
            "centeredMessage" : "",
            "chatCommonIdentifier" : "0tQ3BrPCWzl2021073014020032",
            "chatDate" : "30/07/2021",
            "chatDescription" : "Firebase Url (Hidden for security reasons)",
            "chatPresented" : "0",
            "chatRead" : "0",
            "chatReceiverTag" : "2",
            "chatSenderTag" : "1",
            "chatTime" : "02:02 PM",
            "chatType" : "Recording",
            "compressed" : "Compressed",
            "deleteAll" : "0",
            "deleteCompletely" : "0",
            "deleteSelf" : "0",
            "downloaded" : "0",
            "fcmStatus" : "1",
            "fileLocalPath" : "",
            "groupChat" : "",
            "inOut" : "Incoming",
            "replyingTo" : "",
            "roomId" : "",
            "timeStamp" : 1627633960112,
            "uploaded" : "0",
            "uploadedToStorage" : "1"
          },
          "jOMfAYxsMFg2021073014020015" : {
            "backgroundTaskIndicator" : "0",
            "centeredMessage" : "",
            "chatCommonIdentifier" : "jOMfAYxsMFg2021073014020015",
            "chatDate" : "30/07/2021",
            "chatDescription" : "hi",
            "chatPresented" : "0",
            "chatRead" : "0",
            "chatReceiverTag" : "2",
            "chatSenderTag" : "1",
            "chatTime" : "02:02 PM",
            "chatType" : "Text",
            "compressed" : "Compressed",
            "deleteAll" : "0",
            "deleteCompletely" : "0",
            "deleteSelf" : "0",
            "downloaded" : "0",
            "fcmStatus" : "1",
            "fileLocalPath" : "",
            "groupChat" : "",
            "inOut" : "Incoming",
            "replyingTo" : "",
            "roomId" : "",
            "timeStamp" : 1627633935879,
            "uploaded" : "0",
            "uploadedToStorage" : "1"
          }
        },
        "2-1" : {
          "0tQ3BrPCWzl2021073014020032" : {
            "backgroundTaskIndicator" : "1",
            "centeredMessage" : "",
            "chatCommonIdentifier" : "0tQ3BrPCWzl2021073014020032",
            "chatDate" : "30/07/2021",
            "chatDescription" : "Firebase Url (Hidden for security reasons)",
            "chatGroup" : "",
            "chatPresented" : "0",
            "chatRead" : "0",
            "chatReceiverCommonIdentifiers" : "",
            "chatReceiverTag" : "1",
            "chatSenderTag" : "2",
            "chatTime" : "02:02 PM",
            "chatType" : "Recording",
            "compressed" : "Compressed",
            "deleteAll" : "0",
            "deleteCompletely" : "0",
            "deleteSelf" : "0",
            "downloaded" : "0",
            "fcmStatus" : "1",
            "fileLocalPath" : "file:///storage/emulated/0/app/app%20Recordings/Recording_app_22_2021_07_30_02_02_27.3gp",
            "inOut" : "Outgoing",
            "mediaDuration" : "00:04",
            "replyingTo" : "",
            "roomId" : "",
            "timeStamp" : 1627633952117,
            "uploaded" : "1",
            "uploadedToStorage" : "1"
          },
          "jOMfAYxsMFg2021073014020015" : {
            "backgroundTaskIndicator" : "0",
            "centeredMessage" : "",
            "chatCommonIdentifier" : "jOMfAYxsMFg2021073014020015",
            "chatDate" : "30/07/2021",
            "chatDescription" : "hi",
            "chatGroup" : "",
            "chatPresented" : "0",
            "chatRead" : "0",
            "chatReceiverCommonIdentifiers" : "",
            "chatReceiverTag" : "1",
            "chatSenderTag" : "2",
            "chatTime" : "02:02 PM",
            "chatType" : "Text",
            "compressed" : "Compressed",
            "deleteAll" : "0",
            "deleteCompletely" : "0",
            "deleteSelf" : "0",
            "downloaded" : "0",
            "fcmStatus" : "1",
            "fileLocalPath" : "",
            "inOut" : "Outgoing",
            "mediaDuration" : "",
            "replyingTo" : "",
            "roomId" : "",
            "timeStamp" : 1627633935409,
            "uploaded" : "1",
            "uploadedToStorage" : "1"
          }
        }
      },
      "Users" : {
        "1" : {
          "fcm" : "fkvEQqsjTqOuDqQB0JmAyc:APA91bFVaysxs_dxsXcwjYkDlHRIqRYfsbMDGaBTaq1xu0VoiJwX0e1gPIRtm3yNZiYg_I28qu9U58rll6wDMRGunsiZ347B1Me2nUv5Qzt3ec1xNMpEQKlkxsBhPEzoJWNCO6KDSMT9",
          "ref" : "41"
        },
        "2" : {
          "fcm" : "fxOMlDCgQJ6KNGboVaxXZ_:APA91bFQ1FFGYQI6dZmqNfxXbsG799HnEk8VBkqoJYlI7IBi2mz5WMHgMjM44bNFVjR58d_8dZVzKOIRvmfmfCQxgjDsO4MXuVQcpz-RpbYb3s0EQDl67YhlZM1YJQDBaOFBAuwI4MF3",
          "ref" : "44"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Besides that, **how many children exist under `senderNode`?**

Comment: @AlexMamo, question is updated now. Thanks.

Comment: How many children in total exist under `senderNode`? Only two?

Comment: Right now only 2 chat nodes, yes. But they will increase in future as you know. I mean there would be lot of chats between users.

Comment: So you say that reading those two messages, takes 2-3 seconds? Are you performing other heavy operations in other parts of your code?

Comment: I am only doing some multi-conditioning with data received in `onBindViewHolder`, not calling more `DataReference` here. But there are lot of conditions.

Comment: I was not asking about conditions, I was asking about any other database queries that can take some time?

Comment: Okay, I have 2 database quires including `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`. another is `addValueEventListener' for users node. both are running on separate threads. That's it.

Comment: Is your device losing internet connectivity?

Comment: No, internet is stable. In the meanwhile, I created a test activity and just ran `startFirebaseRecyclerViewOptions()` only, and interestingly, that was quick.